# Nested Tradução errada Inflection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Opa,

O problema é o seguinte:
Tenho uma Model Chamada Ideia e estou tentando adicionar um novo nested nela para IdeiaCategoria que é uma associativa com Ideia. Então temos:

Ideia:
has_many :ideia_categorias, inverse_of: :ideia, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ideia_categorias, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

IdeiaCategoria:
belongs_to :ideia
belongs_to :categoria

Categoria:
has_many :ideia_categorias, inverse_of: :categoria, dependent: :destroy

No meu form de Ideia tenho assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando eu entro nesse form me retorna o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no meu inflection está assim essa parte das ideias:

```
inflect.plural "ideia_comentario", "ideia_comentarios"
inflect.singular "ideia_comentarios", "ideia_comentario"

inflect.plural "ideia_arquivo", "ideia_arquivos"
inflect.singular "ideia_arquivos", "ideia_arquivo"

inflect.plural "ideia_categoria", "ideia_categorias"
inflect.singular "ideia_categorias", "ideia_categoria"

inflect.plural "categoria", "categorias"
inflect.singular "categorias", "categoria"
```

Da onde que está puxando esse IdeiaCategorium?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai uma sugestão de como colocar no seu arquivo de inflections:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.clear

  inflect.plural(/$/,  's')
  inflect.plural(/(s)$/i,  '\1')
  inflect.plural(/^(paí)s$/i, '\1ses')
  inflect.plural(/(z|r)$/i, '\1es')
  inflect.plural(/al$/i,  'ais')
  inflect.plural(/el$/i,  'eis')
  inflect.plural(/ol$/i,  'ois')
  inflect.plural(/ul$/i,  'uis')
  inflect.plural(/([^aeou])il$/i,  '\1is')
  inflect.plural(/m$/i,   'ns')
  inflect.plural(/^(japon|escoc|ingl|dinamarqu|fregu|portugu)ês$/i,  '\1eses')
  inflect.plural(/^(|g)ás$/i,  '\1ases')
  inflect.plural(/ão$/i,  'ões')
  inflect.plural(/^(irm|m)ão$/i,  '\1ãos')
  inflect.plural(/^(alem|c|p)ão$/i,  '\1ães')

  # Sem acentos...
  inflect.plural(/ao$/i,  'oes')
  inflect.plural(/mês$/i,  'meses')
  inflect.plural(/^(irm|m)ao$/i,  '\1aos')
  inflect.plural(/^(alem|c|p)ao$/i,  '\1aes')

  inflect.singular(/([^ê])s$/i, '\1')
  inflect.singular(/^(á|gá|paí)s$/i, '\1s')
  inflect.singular(/(r|z)es$/i, '\1')
  inflect.singular(/([^p])ais$/i, '\1al')
  inflect.singular(/eis$/i, 'el')
  inflect.singular(/ois$/i, 'ol')
  inflect.singular(/uis$/i, 'ul')
  inflect.singular(/(r|t|f|v)is$/i, '\1il')
  inflect.singular(/ns$/i, 'm')
  inflect.singular(/sses$/i, 'sse')
  inflect.singular(/^(.*[^s]s)es$/i, '\1')
  inflect.singular(/ães$/i, 'ão')
  inflect.singular(/aes$/i, 'ao')
  inflect.singular(/ãos$/i, 'ão')
  inflect.singular(/aos$/i, 'ao')
  inflect.singular(/ões$/i, 'ão')
  inflect.singular(/oes$/i, 'ao')
  inflect.singular(/(japon|escoc|ingl|dinamarqu|fregu|portugu)eses$/i, '\1ês')
  inflect.singular(/^(g|)ases$/i,  '\1ás')
  inflect.irregular('palavra_chave', 'palavras_chaves')
  inflect.irregular('joao_ninguem', 'jooes_ninguem')
end
```

As duas últimas linhas é para o caso de você querer colocar plural nas duas palavras como seria o caso do plural de um substantivo composto.